# Powershell Userdata not executed while launching EC2 instance through Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-lambda

I have created AWS Lambda python3.6 function to launch new windows ec2 instance. Additionally i have added powershell script as user data while launching new instance. But instance has been launched successfully. But user data is not executed.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import os
    import boto3
    AMI = os.environ["AMI"]
    INSTANCE_TYPE = os.environ["INSTANCE_TYPE"]
    KEY_NAME = os.environ["KEY_NAME"]
    SUBNET_ID = os.environ["SUBNET_ID"]
    REGION = os.environ["REGION"]
    ec2 = boto3.client("ec2", region_name=REGION)
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        init_script = '''
            <powershell>
            $USERNAME="Latchu"
            $PASSWORD="eM2An@ydxk"
            net user /add $USERNAME $PASSWORD
            </powershell>'''
instance = ec2.run_instances(
    ImageId=AMI,
    InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
    KeyName=KEY_NAME,
    SubnetId=SUBNET_ID,
    MaxCount=1,
    MinCount=1,
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior="terminate",
    UserData=init_script,
)
```

After lauched EC2 instance logon to windows server and i had a look. But it seems, user not created. Am i missing anything in my code?

Comment: I suspect that the indents are causing problems. Start by viewing the User Data in the EC2 management console, to confirm that it is appearing. Check the log in `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2Launch\log\agent.log`. Try removing the spaces at the start of the lines, especially the first link with `<powershell>`. Let us know how that goes!

Comment: I have removed <powershell> and extra spaces in userdata. Then i tried to start lambda function. But no luck.

Comment: Sorry. Now its working after adding <powershell> and remove spaces in userdata script. Many thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software on the instance checks whether the first line is `<powershell>`.

It is likely that the spaces at the start of the line stop this from working, so the script is not executed.

Comment: After removed extra spaces in powershell script and applied on Lambda function. Its working fine. But i didn't remove <powershell> and  </powershell>. Many thanks for your suggestion.